# Manually intercept a dispatch in react-native using react-native-offline

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, offline

I know [react-native-offline](https://github.com/rgommezz/react-native-offline) has a `interceptInOffline` property that will automatically store your dispatch if you don't have an internet connection. But how do you manually intercept your dispatch? I want to intercept it manually if my connection is slow and just retry again once the connection is better. I currently use `NetInfo` to determine the connection type and effective connection type.

Comment: why don't you just retry the request if it fails?

Comment: @Jan there are times when the user can upload huge amounts of data (e.g. images, documents, etc.), I wanted to intercept it manually and just store the payload for later when the user has a better connection instead of wasting bandwidth trying to upload that has a high chance of failing.

Comment: You can try background uploads. It should be their problem if their trying to upload big files.

Answer (score 0):

You need to create your own redux middleware and put it inside applyMiddlware method